# AppCompat library doesn't include Theme.AppCompat. "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-theme

So I basically want to build a `TabActivity` in AndroidStudio and I am using an `AppCompatActivity`.

If I run my code, I get an error like that one:

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

I am using this in gradle:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.8'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0"
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
```

If I want to create a style with `Theme.AppCompat`, it says:

> Cannot resolve 'Theme.AppCompat'

Currently I am using this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_01</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/action_bar_01</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/status_bar_color</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/action_bar_01</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_app</item>
</style>
```

What should I do?

Comment: try  this  clean and rebuild

Comment: post the full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity instead of AppCompatActivity.

Change :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

To:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

Comment: I can't use this because then I can't use everything in my Activity

Answer (score 0):

As the error said, you need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme for your activity. This means you should change your style parent from

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">`
into something like
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">`

Remember to remove android prefix from `colorPrimaryDark` and `colorPrimary` so they become

`<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_01</item>
 <item name="colorPrimary">@color/action_bar_01</item>`

You'll find more info from official Android documentation about [Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: That's what I said, if I use Theme.AppCompat, i have the error: cannot resolve Theme.AppCompat, because it seems that the AppCompat Theme isn't in any library

Comment: The style you are currently using in your configuration is wrong. Edit your question if you are not using `android:Theme.Material.Light` as a parent theme. Or the community will not be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'` to your gradle file

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html) tutorial, if you are using the AppCompactActivity you can use for style `parent` attribute: **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** or **Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar**

i.e.: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

I hope this works.